# php sum result issues

Tags: php, laravel, sum

while adding the value and returning the result, it returns the correct value but when we return array values it is showing result with decimal values as shown in the below:

```
<?php return [1.4 + 11.3];  ?>
Output: 12.700000000000001

<?php return (1.4 + 11.3);  ?>
Output: 12.7
```

How to resolve these issues? Any help would be great.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't post code as screenshots.

Comment: @rupesh-mdr Instead of images, you can use [Code Block](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/code-blocks/). Also, you can check this [Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361).

Comment: That's how computers work when it comes to floating point numbers. It's normally fine, you just cannot assume infinite precision. Decide how many decimals you need and `round()` on display.

Answer (score 0):

This is known problem when getting currency from database.
I assume you use column type decimal.

There are some solution available:

1. Use casts `[ 'amount' => 'decimal:2', ]`
2. You can use a getter (laravel mutators) inside your model, formatting the result you get from db  `round($value, 2)`
3. Use `brick/money` library or `laravel-money` package (but this solution is not for everyone)
4. Another solution, which the one I use, is converting column to type integer. You need to use mutator : setter convert decimal into integer, `value 11.3 into 1130`.and getter to process into decimal, `from 1130 back into 11.3`.